# EmojiCompat listing emojis dynamically

Tags: android, emoji

I'm currently using EmojiCompat library on android and I wanted to know how to list all emojis available.
I have 3 options :

- Display all emojis in a custom emoji keyboard, based on EmojiCompat
- Show an existing bundled emoji keyboard able to display **all** EmojiCompat's emojis
- If those are not possible, at least display all emojis available on the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google released [Jetpack Emoji picker](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/08/introducing-jetpack-emoji-picker.html), which is exactly what I needed